# while ... readdir causing segmentation fault

Tags: c

In main I call the following function with deletefolder():

```
void deletefolder(){

   struct dirent *next_file;
   DIR *folder;

   char filepath[256];

   folder = opendir("./game/wow");

   while((next_file = readdir(folder)) != NULL){ //this is causing the segmentation fault. I don't know why?


      sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", "./game/wow", next_file->d_name);
      remove(filepath);
   }
}
```

I can't figure out why it is happening?

Comment: next_file is pointing to a struct so in the line `while((next_file = readdir(folder)) != NULL){` are you sure you didnt mean to put next_file pointing to one of the variables in the struct. `next_file->struct_variable = readdir(folder)) != NULL){`

Comment: Add code to check whether `folder` is `NULL` before calling `readdir`.

Comment: that in the while is only to see as a condition from my understanding. it means as long there is a file, it is true and keeps running it. in sprintf it points to the variable in the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> while((next_file = readdir(folder)) != NULL){ //this is causing the segmentation fault. i dont know why??
> ```

I suspect there was an error in opening the directory. Add some error checking code.

```
folder = opendir("./game/wow");
if ( folder == NULL )
{
   perror("Unable to open folder.");
   return;
}

while((next_file = readdir(folder)) != NULL){ ...
```

Comment: folder not found; perror -> no such file or directory <- perror . maybe its worth mentioning i open this from osx with double click. files do exist inside that folder and when i open it from within the terminal with sudo its actually working.

Comment: The next thing you can check is the print the current working directory before the call to `opendir`.

Comment: i used <unistd.h> with the code - > char cwd[1024]; getcwd(cwd,255); printf("%s",cwd); <- to see the directory and it is the home directory, not the programmdirectory. thats why i get that s.f.11 . bit weird, since it works from the terminal. ah, well, thanks. guided me into the right direction ;)